# Swift - NSMangedObjectContext in relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am new to swift and especially to core data so please if my title is wrong just tell me.

So i have Three entities:

Home

AgendaEvent

AgendaDate

Home has a relationship one to many with AgendaEvent (agendaEvents).
AgendaEvent has a relationship one to many with AgendaDate (agendaDates).

I have a tableview with a list of all Homes (Home entity).
By clicking one home the user goes in another tableview with a list of all Events (AgendaEvent)

If I need to add a new event everything works fine. When adding an event I also add dates (AgendaDates)

```
------saving the event
for date in dates { // dates array is defined before

            if agendaEventToEdit == nil {
                dateToAdd = AgendaDate(context:context)
            } else {
------------
```

I pass the agendaEventToEdit with a segue when the user selects an event from the tableView.

Here's my issue:
If I need to modify an event I can easily modify the event itself (AgendaEvent) like so:

```
 if agendaEventToEdit == nil {
            agendaEvent = AgendaEvent(context:context)
        } else {
            agendaEvent = agendaEventToEdit
        }
```

Where context is defined in my Appdelegate.

But I don't know how to modify the dates (AgendaDate)

```
 for date in dates {

            if agendaEventToEdit == nil { // here is the case where user is adding new event and not modifying an existing one.
                dateToAdd = AgendaDate(context:context)
            } else {
                dateToAdd = ??
            }

            dateToAdd.agendaDates = date
            agendaEvent.addToAgendaDates(dateToAdd)
            ad.saveContext()
        }
```

Basically I don't know how to pass the NSManagedObjectContext of the entity related.
Anybody can help?
Hope the question is clear... if not please excuse me... and I'll try to make it clearer.

Thank you!

-------------------UPDATE

In my event controller when i select an event to modify i pass to a new controller the event itself:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var eventToPass: AgendaEvent!

    eventToPass = myEvents[indexPath.row]
    DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "EventToModify", sender: eventToPass)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "AddEvent" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? EventDetailsVC {
            destination.datePassed = selectedDate
        }
    } else if segue.identifier == "EventToModify" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? EventDetailsVC {
            if let event = sender as? AgendaEvent {
                destination.agendaEventToEdit = event

            }
        }
    }
}
```

so now in EventDetailsVC If agendaEventToEdit is nil it means it's new event to add if it's not then it's an event to modify. Here's the code:

```
var agendaEvent: AgendaEvent!
 if agendaEventToEdit == nil {
            agendaEvent = AgendaEvent(context:context)
        } else {
            agendaEvent = agendaEventToEdit
        }
......
home.addToAgendaEvents(agendaEvent)
        ad.saveContext()
```

I'm trying to do the same with the agendaEvents which are also added from the EventDetailsVC

```
var dateToAdd: AgendaDate!
 if agendaEventToEdit == nil {
                dateToAdd = AgendaDate(context:context)
            } else {
                dateToAdd = ??

            }

            dateToAdd.agendaDates = date
            agendaEvent.addToAgendaDates(dateToAdd)
            ad.saveContext()
        }
```

but I'm not able to determine the dateToAdd in the else

Comment: The event will have a set for event dates, so you may need to loop through that set to look for a specific date to edit.  OR, if you just always want to add a new date, then you don't need your "if" statement: just always create a new one and add it as you are.

Comment: @conarch in the same controller i might need to create a new one or to update an EventDate... to create a new one no problem... but when updating... well i don't know how to get the AgendaDate related to the AgendaEvent. I need to update the whole attribute of the entity because the dat might have changed completely... If i Loop through i will get the single dates, what i need is the managedobjectcontext for the agendaDate in order to pass it here: dateToAdd.agendaDates = date agendaEvent.addToAgendaDates(dateToAdd)

Comment: I'm clearly not understanding the issue, but I will say that every managed object has a property that tells you its context.  If you have the event, then use that event's context.

Comment: i’ll Update my question to try to explain better...sorry but i’m Totally new to core data...so probably i’m Not able to explain it in the best way...

Comment: I think it's ok if you're basic question is "how do I get the context".  In that case, you already have it: it's simply a property on your event that was passed via the segue.

Comment: I've updated my question... yes I have the context but for the AgendaEvent... I need the context of the AgendaDate relative to the AgendaEvent i've selected...

Comment: @conarch maybe i can fetch the agendaDate entity relative to the agendaEventToEdit...?

Comment: They should almost certainly be the same context unless you've intentionally created a temporary one (I suspect you haven't).  There are no special steps for you to worry about.

Comment: @conarch i haven't..if i just use AgendaDate(context:context) then when updating it just add the dates... even if they already exists... i was trying to add dates if they don't exist inside the NSSet and do nothing if the NSSet already contains that date...

Comment: which however i don't get because i thought a Set could have just unique values...

Comment: A set does only have "unique", and they are because your NEW object isn't the same object as the one that exists (even if they represent the same date).  You need to look through the dates manually to see if the new one is a dupe.

Comment: so there is no other way to overwrite the existing one..? i need to loop through allobjects and if the date is not there add it?

Comment: You can either find the existing one and modify it, or delete that one and create your new one.  But yeah, you'll need to loop through and check for a dupe or you might be able to use a predicate if you feel a little fancy. (loop for now to make it work, try a predicate later if you feel braver)

Comment: ok i will try! Thx a lot for your help!